# clvm (cman) has problems with dlm

Tags: lvm, cluster, distributed-filesystem

I am trying to create a volume group which is accessible on two servers with clvm. I read about it and it looks like it is most easily to do this with cman. But after hours of testing I cannot achieve a setup that works. I cannot start clvmd and I am frustrated because I cannot find a reason for it. Why does it say that it cannot connect to a local socket? What socket is meant by it? And after a few seconds there are problems with dlm (see below).

```
# clvmd -fd2 -I cman
local socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
clvmd could not connect to cluster manager
Consult syslog for more information

# tail /var/log/syslog
... clvmd[765]: CLVMD started
... clvmd[765]: Connected to CMAN
... clvmd[765]: CMAN initialisation complete
... kernel: [ 1069.787540] dlm: Using TCP for communications
... kernel: [ 1069.787874] dlm: c: joining the lockspace group...
... kernel: [ 1069.795626] dlm: c: group event done 0 0
... kernel: [ 1069.795628] dlm: c: dlm_recover 1
... kernel: [ 1069.795674] dlm: c: add member 1
... kernel: [ 1069.795676] dlm: c: dlm_recover_members 1 nodes
... kernel: [ 1069.795678] dlm: c: generation 1 slots 1 1:1
... kernel: [ 1069.795679] dlm: c: dlm_recover_directory
... kernel: [ 1069.795679] dlm: c: dlm_recover_directory 0 in 0 new
... kernel: [ 1069.795680] dlm: c: dlm_recover_directory 0 out 0 messages
... kernel: [ 1069.795705] dlm: c: dlm_recover 1 generation 1 done: 0 ms
... kernel: [ 1069.797183] dlm: c: join complete
... clvmd[765]: Unable to create DLM lockspace for CLVM: No such file or directory
... clvmd[765]: Can't initialise cluster interface
```

I read several internet resources that described problems with the dlm setup. But to me it does not look like there is a problem:

```
# ls -l /dev/dlm*
crw-rw---- 1 root root 10, 56 Apr  3 10:22 /dev/dlm_c
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 59 Apr  3 10:20 /dev/dlm-control
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 58 Apr  3 10:20 /dev/dlm-monitor
crw-rw---- 1 root root 10, 57 Apr  3 10:20 /dev/dlm_plock
# lsmod|grep dlm
dlm                   157924  13 
sctp                  299454  3 dlm
configfs               31664  2 dlm
```

Maybe I have forgotten to create an essential config entry. I am new to the topic. My test environment consists of two virtual debian hosts (test1 and test2). cman_tool states that they are connected properly together. Here is my /etc/cluster/cluster.conf

```
<cluster name="mycluster" config_version="4">
   <cman two_node="1" expected_votes="1"/>
   <clusternodes>
     <clusternode name="test1" nodeid="1">
        <fence>
        </fence>
     </clusternode>
     <clusternode name="test2" nodeid="2">
        <fence>
        </fence>
     </clusternode>
   </clusternodes>

   <fencedevices>
   </fencedevices>

   <rm>
   </rm>
</cluster>
```

Any hints that get me closer to the source of the problem are very welcome!